# Angularjs Seo problems

Tags: angularjs, django, seo, prerender

I have a website , and I`m using AngularJs.Everythings works fine but when I try to search my website on google I get a lot of brackets :

```
Dobuy.T-shirts. Home. Search Product. Designer; [[item.name]];
Category; [[item.name]]; My Account; Cart · Checkout · Login 
· User Profile · ([[cartItems]] items) ...
```

I heard that if i use prerender.io this will solve my problem, so i gave it a try but the page is the same .. nothing changed.
I am using django with the django prerender package.
Any idea ? Any help ? How can I make my AngularJs website SEO friendly ?

Comment: What is that site? I heard, google crawler successfull crawl every js content, but i never tried.

Comment: www.dobuytshirts.com

Comment: Can you tried re-crawl from [https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-fetch-details](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-fetch-details)

Comment: I dont understand how will this help.Just submited my website.

Comment: Are you used google webmaster tools? When you add your website, you can simulate google crawl - in my link? Are you try GWT?

Comment: Because, you can found something cached data in google index, but crawled data is different.

Comment: It seems that google has no problem on reading the website. But when i search on google i got a lot of brackets from an ng-repeat.I don t think is about cached data ..

Comment: Sounds like you might not have installed your middleware correctly. Feel free to send me an email at todd@prerender.io and I'd be happy to help!

Comment: i finally get it working with the nginx middleware instead of the django middleware.Now everything works fine.Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 1):

You don't set up your prerender.io correctly. Just check url: view-source:http://www.dobuytshirts.com/?_escaped_fragment_= and you can see all brackets.

Comment: because prerender.io was not working i changed to https://github.com/steeve/angular-seo and phantomjs. But it's still not working.

Comment: If have problems with prerender set up, you can use prerender as a service: https://prerender.io/pricing

Comment: i finnaly get it working using nginx middleware instead of django middleware. thanks for helping